# Removing notifications from iOS notification tray

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to remove all notifications from the notification centre of iOS when a user logs out of the app. This is the code that I am using:

```
// Clear out notifications from the notification centre and reset notification badge on the home page
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Is there anything that I am missing.

Comment: I think no. Are you facing a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is not clearing out the notifications that were delivered to the app via APN and are still in the notification centre. Hence the question :)